# SQL fetch rows based on value from seperate table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables inside of the database `Employees`:

- Table `employee`

  - `emp_number` PRIMARY KEY (INT)
  - `first_name` (TEXT)
  - `last_name` (TEXT)
- Table `salary`

  - `emp_number` FOREIGN KEY `employee.emp_number`
  - `salary` (INT)

I would like to fetch all employees that make a salary over 80,000.

Comment: Please edit your question and add in the query that demonstrates your best attempt at resolving this yourself, and then explain at what point in that query you aren't getting the results you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can simply use Inner JOIN to join the two tables. and sometimes you might wonder what is the `em` and `s`. It's called SQL aliases. which are used to give a table, or a column in a table, a temporary name.

```
SELECT em.first_name,
       e.last_name
FROM   employees em
       INNER JOIN salary s
               ON s.emp_number = em.emp_number
WHERE  s.salary > 80000
```

Read more about SQL JOIN , WHERE Clause and aliases from here

[SQL Aliases](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp)

[MySQL greater than or equal operator](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/greater-than-or-equal-operator.php)

[SQL Joins](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT employees.first_name,employees.last_name FROM employees.employees
INNER JOIN employees.salaries.salary on salaries.emp_no= employees.emp_no
WHERE salaries.salary>80000

Comment: i still got an error

Comment: @Olesia Try this SELECT DISTINCT emp.first_name,
                emp.last_name
FROM   employees emp
       INNER JOIN salary salaries
               ON salaries.emp_no = emp.emp_no
WHERE  salaries.salary > 80000

Comment: @Olesia And let me know if there is an error. or unclear part

Comment: so that db is Employees and it contains table Employees and table Salaries.

Comment: when i put salaries.salary it said unknown database and when i put employees.salaries.salary its said syntax error

Comment: @Olesia try this, make sure to use the correct database,

SELECT DISTINCT emp.first_name,
                emp.last_name
FROM   Employees emp
       INNER JOIN Salaries sal
               ON sal.emp_no = emp.emp_no
WHERE  sal.salary > 80000

Comment: no :( now its only displays first and last name but no salary attached.

Comment: @Olesia try this to take the salary as well.
SELECT DISTINCT emp.first_name,
                emp.last_name,
  sal.salary 
FROM   employees emp
       INNER JOIN salaries sal
               ON sal.emp_no = emp.emp_no
WHERE  sal.salary > 80000

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a [`JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) operation which can be used to fetch a result of results based on values from one or more tables. By combining tables into one result, you can then filter the ones that match by foreign key using the `ON` statement.

```sql
SELECT e.first_name, e.last_name
FROM employees e
INNER JOIN salary s
ON s.emp_number = e.emp_number
WHERE salary.salary > 80000
```